# Background Process Stops after 5 minutes - PHP and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cron, devops

I am running a WordPress website, which runs CRON for very large data. Typically the CRON runs for 2 to 2:30 hours.

But from last 2 days, I am facing an issue like my CRON process is getting stuck after **5 minutes** i.e. 300 seconds

I have tried to resolve this using the below solutions:

1. Added `set_time_limit(0);` in wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '4096' );
set_time_limit(300);
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '4096' );
```

2. Added `php_value max_execution_time 18000` in .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule php7_module>
  php_value max_execution_time 18000
  php_value max_input_time 6000
  php_value memory_limit 4096M
  php_flag display_errors Off
  php_value max_input_vars 1000
  php_value post_max_size 8M
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
  php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
  php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
  php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
```

3. In /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file, increased the `Timeout` variable with value `5000`
4. Increased value of `FcgidBusyTimeout` with `5000`

None of the above solutions worked for me.

Anyone can help to find where is the problem with this cron or with other validation steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this to server support guys as well, and they came up with the solution.

Anyone having the same issue can try modifying values:

In my case, Filename: `/etc/apache2/conf.d/lsapi.conf`

1. `lsapi_poll_timeout 18000`
2. `lsapi_backend_max_process_time 18000`

After applying these changes, you need to restart the `APACHE` server for reflecting the changes.

Applying these changes worked for me.